# OpenGL not rendering full scene, it is a mystery

Tags: c#, opengl, rendering, transformation, opentk

I am trying to draw a scene in the sort of style of mock vector graphics. I've helped on a 2D game before with GLSL, but I tried to keep a simple approach to this project since I'm working by myself, and I want to get the mechanics down before I have to fiddle too seriously with the graphics.

My problem is, for some befuddling (but probably simple) reason, not all of my scene is being rendered. Let me try to explain with my code ...

```
public class Game
{
    public static GameWindow gamewindow;

    ...

    public delegate void drawhandler(object sender, FrameEventArgs e);
    public static event drawhandler draw;

    public Game()
    {
        gamewindow = new GameWindow();
        gamewindow.Load += load;
        gamewindow.Resize += resize;
        gamewindow.UpdateFrame += update;
        gamewindow.RenderFrame += render;
        gamewindow.Run(60.0);
    }

    GameState.Ship ship;
    GameState.Space space;
    Camera camera;

    void load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gamewindow.VSync = VSyncMode.On;
        gamewindow.Width = 8*190;
        gamewindow.Height = 8*120;

        camera = new Camera(new PointF(0,0), new SizeF(gamewindow.Width, gamewindow.Height));
        space = GameState.Space.fromrandom(...);
        foreach (Physical p in space.bodies)
            if (p.GetType() == typeof(GameState.Ship))
                ship = (GameState.Ship)p;

        camera.lookat = ship.position;      
    }

    void resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        camera.viewsize = new SizeF(gamewindow.Width, gamewindow.Height);
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, (int)camera.viewsize.Width, (int)camera.viewsize.Height);
    }

    void update(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }

    void render(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, (int)camera.viewsize.Width, (int)camera.viewsize.Height);
        GL.ClearColor(Color.Black);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        //GL.Ortho(0, vw, 0, vh, 0.0, 4.0);
        camera.setortho();

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        if (draw != null)
            draw(this, e);

        gamewindow.SwapBuffers();           
    }
}
```

So what happens is that the scene "space" is randomly created when loading. In order to draw the objects in "space", I do this:

```
public class Space
{
    public List<Physical> bodies = new List<Physical>();
    ...

    public Space(List<Physical> bodies)
    {
        this.bodies = bodies;
        init();
    }

    void init()
    {
        ...
        Game.draw += draw;
        ...
    }

    ...

    void draw(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Physical body in bodies)
            body.draw(sender, e);
    }

    ...
}
```

And finally, to draw the hero's ship in that list:

```
public class Ship : Physical
{

    ...

    public override void draw(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        GL.PushMatrix();
            GL.Color3(color);
            GL.Translate(position.X, position.Y, 0);
            // HACK debug thrust vector
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Lines);
                GL.Vertex2(0f,0f);
                GL.Vertex2(velocity.X*100, velocity.Y*100);
            GL.End();
            //
            GL.Rotate(rotation, 0, 0, -1);
            GL.Scale(SCALE, SCALE, SCALE);
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.LineLoop);
                GL.Vertex2(-1.0f, -1.0f);
                GL.Vertex2(-0f, 1.0f);
                GL.Vertex2(1.0f, -1.0f);
                GL.Vertex2(-0.0f, -0.5f);
            GL.End();
        GL.PopMatrix();
    }

    ...

}
```

Simple enough, this works as expected. The only other things I am drawing are "planets", which are simply circle line loops. Now let's draw a quad right in the middle for the hell of it ...

```
GL.PushMatrix();
    GL.Color3(Color.Orange);
    //GL.Translate(0, 0, 0);
    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
        GL.Vertex2(-50.0f, 50.0f);
        GL.Vertex2(-50.0f, -50.0f);
        GL.Vertex2(50.0f, -50.0f);
        GL.Vertex2(50.0f, 50.0f); 
    GL.End();
GL.PopMatrix();
```

I'll put this after I invoke the "draw" event and before I swap buffers in the render method. Upon running, nothing changes!

I am almost certain that I am making a trivial mistake, but stepping through the code line by line I can find no error. I appreciate any advice in advance.

Comment: Depth buffer? Try turning off the depth buffer :) glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); <-- Do that once

Comment: Gave it a try, no go. But there's no real reason I should be worried about the depth buffer (I believe) since everything is being drawn to the same depth. It's a habit from a previous episode of "why is nothing working right".

Comment: Depth buffer bit me more than twice.. it is enabled by default i a mode where even drawing in the same depth hides future draws. My next try would be to isolate only that last rectangle (comment out drawing everything before thst)

Comment: Excellent idea! I've got a green quad now, and nothing else. Hopefully I can just keep moving this quad back further in the code and see where it gets tangled up.

Comment: Glad i could help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Lennart Rolland](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/25563/lennart-rolland), I found out that the third-party font library I was using (QFont) had a bug in the way it manages its matricies. By moving my quad around in the drawing code, I was able to see where it got mangled. Thanks again for the help!